# OpenTK 半透過方法

Tags: c#, opengl

現在C# OpenTKを使って3Dグラフィックスを描いています

質問は半透過ブラック(0,0,0,0.5)でGL.Clearすることはできるか教えてください。

現在、音楽波形をLinesを使って、描画しています
その際、毎回黒でclearするのではなく、
半透過の黒でclearすることで、
1フレーム前の線を薄く残し、ブラーのような演出にならないかと思っているのですが
GL.ClearColor(0,0,0,0.5)としても、
透過の無い黒でしかクリアされず、半透明の線が残ることはありません。

前フレームの色を透過させて残すことはできないでしょうか？

ご教授頂けると幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
        GL.ClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Lines);

        int N = dataset.Length;
        for (int n = 1; n < N; n++)
        {
            float v1 = dataset[n - 1];
            float v2 = dataset[n];

            Vector3 zero = 0.5f * (py - p0) + p0;
            Vector3 nx = px - p0;

            Vector3 P1 = zero + nx * (float)(n - 1) / N;
            Vector3 P2 = zero + nx * (float)n / N;

            Vector3 Value1 = v1 * (py - p0) * 0.5f;
            Vector3 Value2 = v2 * (py - p0) * 0.5f;

            P1 = P1 + Value1;
            P2 = P2 + Value2;

            GL.Color3(Color.Red);
            GL.Vertex3(P1);
            GL.Vertex3(P2);

        }
        GL.End();

        // SwapBuffer
        SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

質問をするときは最低限のマナーとして、まず環境に関する情報を詳しく書くようにしてください。
OS、デバイスドライバー、IDE、SDK、ライブラリなどのバージョン、ハードウェアの型番など、提示すべき情報は多岐に渡ります。

[技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html#env)

glClearColor()およびglClear()でアルファチャンネルを任意の値にクリア（一律設定）することはできますが、動作はあくまで値クリアであり、前回の描画結果に都合よく値をブレンドするものではありません。また、デフォルトのフレームバッファ（バックバッファ）は常に不透過となります。

OpenGLで前回（前フレーム）の描画結果との合成を実現したい場合は、フレームバッファオブジェクト (FBO) を使います。2Dテクスチャに描画結果を保存しておき、次のフレームで矩形ポリゴンに張り付けてアルファ合成します。バッファはピンポン方式で使いまわします。

- 【以下は初期化処理】

  1. FBO×2とRGBA 2Dテクスチャ×2を作成（深度バッファの作成は任意）
  2. 2DテクスチャをそれぞれのFBOにバインド（深度バッファのバインドは任意）
- 【以下はレンダリングループ】

  1. FBO#1をGLコンテキストにバインド（描画ターゲットが2Dテクスチャ#1になる）
  2. (0,0,0,0)でクリア
  3. 深度バッファ書込を無効化して、2Dテクスチャ#2を等倍で半透明描画
  4. 深度バッファ書込を有効化して、シーンをレンダリング
  5. バックバッファ（フレームバッファ0）をGLコンテキストにバインド
  6. 任意の背景色でクリアして、2Dテクスチャ#1を等倍で描画
  7. FBO#2をGLコンテキストにバインド（描画ターゲットが2Dテクスチャ#2になる）
  8. (0,0,0,0)でクリア
  9. 深度バッファ書込を無効化して、2Dテクスチャ#1を等倍で半透明描画
  10. 深度バッファ書込を有効化して、シーンをレンダリング
  11. バックバッファ（フレームバッファ0）をGLコンテキストにバインド
  12. 任意の背景色でクリアして、2Dテクスチャ#2を等倍で描画
  13. FBO#1をGLコンテキストにバインド（描画ターゲットが2Dテクスチャ#1になる）
  14. (0,0,0,0)でクリア
  15. 深度バッファ書込を無効化して、2Dテクスチャ#2を等倍で半透明描画
  16. 深度バッファ書込を有効化して、シーンをレンダリング
  17. バックバッファ（フレームバッファ0）をGLコンテキストにバインド
  18. 任意の背景色でクリアして、2Dテクスチャ#1を等倍で描画
      ...

ただし、FBOはOpenGL 3.0で標準化された機能であり、OpenGL 2.1以前では拡張GL_EXT_framebuffer_objectとして提供されています。他に、ピクセルバッファオブジェクト (PBO) を使う方法もありますが、PBOはOpenGL 2.1で標準化された機能であり、OpenGL 2.0以前では拡張GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_objectとして提供されています。

なお、2Dテクスチャを等倍で半透明描画する処理に関しては、コンピュートシェーダーを使う方法もあります。

C#/OpenTKの情報はおそらく手に入りにくく、質・量ともに低いので、C/C++の情報を探したほうが早道です。